# Efficient lookup in MySQL table with millions of rows

Tags: mysql, lookup, latency, large-data

I have a CSV file with about 20 million rows that I'd like to use in my web application. The data is a mapping of postal/zip codes to actual street addresses in the following format:

```
[zip_or_postal_code] [street_number] [street_name] [city] [state_or_province] [country]
```

My goal is to keep my lookups (searching by zip/postal code) under 200ms.

I'm not sure if this would make a difference, but I was planning on doing the following:

- Move the `state/province`, `country`, and `city` columns to their own tables and reference those in my primary table in order to avoid unnecessary bloat.
- Some zip/postal codes cover multiple streets and addresses, so I will consolidate the data and have 1 zip/postal code and will store multiple addresses in something like a varchar. This should cut down a few million rows from the table.

What are some optimizations I could make to help with lookup speed? As an example, Google's reverse geolocation API returns a result in under 300 ms with HTTP overhead included. How do they do it?

Also, I am open to using other databases, but since I'm already using MySQL, that would be preferable.

**Edit**: The lookups will *always* be done by zip/postal code, so as an example: given the zip 12345 I'd need to return the street #(s)/name(s), city, state, and country. The street #(s)/name(s) will be stored as a single string field, however, so my app will take care of parsing them.

Comment: What is the DDL for the table?  Do you have an index in place?  What is a typical query (give SQL)?  If you add those details, it might be easier to comment.

Comment: Have you tried the basic case (one normal table with an index on `zip_code`)? I'm not convinced you *need* anything special for this.

Comment: @seandavi: thank you for your comment. I don't know much about databases yet, so I could only address the query question.

Comment: @BrendanLong: I have not yet, no, because my data contains multiple entries of the same zip code. I'll have to clean it up before I can import it, but I would think that having a table with ~10-15 million rows would result in slow lookups, no?

Comment: @jam3s17 You should proceed assuming that this will work fine.  20M rows is not large by database standards, so I suspect that you are going to be surprised by performance of a simple table with an index on zip-code.

Comment: @seandavi: I hope you're right! Will update this when I'm finished.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

20 million rows is not a lot for MySQL. Just index the zip/postal code and it will be fast. Way under 200ms fast. No need to split between tables. MySQL does get slow when the result set is large, but it doesn't seem like you would encounter that issue. MySQL will do just fine with hundreds of millions of records for basic queries like yours.

You will need to adjust the MySQL settings so that it uses more memory. The default settings are pretty low.

MySQL does support spacial indexes. So you could pull the longitude/latitude for the postal codes and use a spacial index to do proximity searches. Doesn't seem like you are looking for that though.

If you want things really, really fast, go the route you were thinking of but use memcache or redis. You can use the zip/postal code as the lookup key. You would still need a persistant disk based data store to load the data from. I don't think memcache/redis is necessary, but it's an option.

Comment: Sounds promising, thank you! I will clean up my data shortly and try your suggestion. I had no idea MySQL could handle that many records. Will update/accept as soon as I run some tests.

Comment: The largest tables I've used had about 500 millions records. Simple queries had no performance issues.

Comment: Amazing! Did a test run with 4 million (original) rows. Ran it through my consolidation script (as mentioned in the question) and shrunk down the data set to ~750k rows. The profiler tells me that lookups take less than a millisecond (what???) in a VM with less than a gig of RAM. Also, thanks for pointing out spacial index support. Looks interesting.